# Alternative to MS Excel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, excel-formula

I have a situation here.

I am using an Excel template in my `Windows VB.NET` application to read and write values. It's writing values to predefined cells which has some formulas to it and calculating the final output.

I cant use the Excel template anymore for some reason. The only way out I see is writing those formulas in the code itself.

Is there any other way I can achieve the work that Excel template does?? If I only wanted to read values I could have used XML, but here I also want to write.

Sample  - Example of a Cell in Excel Template

> SUM($A$1:$A26) * (Worksheet2!A1*Worksheet2!$B$2)

So data A1 to A26 is calulcated inside my code using various logics. The rest of the data comes from a different worksheet within the excel template.
How can I get this working assuming I want to do the same thing but without the Excel Template?

Comment: What are you calculating? Maybe, you never needed Excel in the first place?

Comment: I am adding some data inside Excel cells(which has Excel formulas internally). I need an alternative.

Comment: I got that, please specify which data inside Excel cells you have and how you are editing it. In short, give more information. Preferably in a form of reduced test case, that fits StackOverflow format.

Comment: updated my question...lemme know if you need more details.

Comment: Do you need to process data in Excel and output to the same Excel file? Or you are just using Excel for calculations, because you feel it's less VB.NET code this way?

Comment: you are right...i was processing data in Excel and also output in Excel file. But I dont want to use Excel anymore. I am just concerned how to do it alternatively.

Comment: Which part are you considering to drop? Excel as a whole? In this case, please specify which data you have and how you process it, give examples, like sample input / sample output. I am assuming that at some point you made a decision to do data processing through Excel and now you are going away from it. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: nope...it was working fine in excel, but now the application is used in a system where Excel is not supported.

Comment: well...finally m calculating one field using different set of formulas and logic.

Comment: If you need to keep Excel files, I can only suggest using a 3rd party library. You can google to find one. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211835/the-best-3rd-party-component-for-generating-excel-spreadsheets-from-asp-net